# Understanding the margin layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am confused by the margin in the console layout which stated both 48 on top and 48 at the bottom. I have used bootstrap to indicate the margin my-5 but on the console it shows 48. Could anyone explain it?

My code is as such:

```
<div class="header my-5 border border-2 border-danger">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation: [Bootstrap - Spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/)

Answer (score 1):

`my-5` uses `5` as spacings. The Bootsrap calculation is by default:

```scss
$spacing: font-size;
0: $spacing * 0;
1: $spacing * 0.25;
2: $spacing * 0.5;
3: $spacing * 1;
4: $spacing * 1.5;
5: $spacing * 3;
auto: auto;
```

With the default font-size of 16px means your `my-5` class will be:

```css
.my-5 {
  margin-top: calc(16px * 3);
  margin-bottom: calc(16px * 3);
}
```

That equals: `16px * 3 = 48px`